# Prestashop Webservice API - Change order state and generate stock movement

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Im using the PrestaShop WebService API to change the order state. To achieve this, I make a POST request like the following:

POST -> https://www.example.com/api/order_histories
Body:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order_history>
    <id/>
    <id_employee>1</id_employee>
    <id_order_state>4</id_order_state>
    <id_order>7</id_order>
    <date_add/>
</order_history>
```

In this scenario, state 4 corresponds to "Sent," causing PrestaShop to reduce the stock of the product. The issue, however, is that it does not generate a new entry in the stock movements, resulting in a loss of traceability in the back office.

How can I force PrestaShop to generate a stock movement entry? I have attempted using the stock_movements resource, but it seems that post, put, and patch operations are not permitted.

Thanks in advance